# How to add to Azure Session Cookies HttpOnly and Secure attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, session-cookies

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application I use a third-party service. And one of the service's terms of use is adding to all session cookies HttpOnly and Secure attributes.

WebSite hosted on Windows Azure and works on SSL.

I added to root web.config the following settings:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

So now my application session cookie ".ASPXAUTH" has HttpOnly and Secure attributes.

But the main problem that Azure Balancer "WAWebSiteSID" and "ARRAffinity" cookies  don't have this attributes.

Could you help me to find appropriate solution to add missing attributes to them?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't believe you can modify the secure and HttpOnly attributes as the cookies are added to the response downstream of the app (i.e. by a load balancing appliance that sits in front of the site).

Of course the pragmatic question is "why"? What advantage would you gain by not allowing client script or an MitM on the wire to access these cookies? They're nothing more than bytes of data intended to tie clients to site instances and contain nothing of a personal nature nor provide any conceivable upside for an attacker (at least not that I can think of).

The answer is probably "because it keeps a security scanning tool happy" which may make you feel warm and fuzzy, but of course it doesn't actually change the practical security position of the site one iota.

Comment: " but of course it doesn't actually change the practical security position of the site one iota." Could you detail why this doesn't? I understand but not everyone does.

Comment: It makes you look like less of a target to potential attackers.

Comment: @Troy If it doesn't change the practical security position then I recommend you make a note on this on Asafaweb since the user of your tool will see the warning and naturally assume there's a problem that should be addressed.

Comment: Now, let's look from a different side and think what BAD will happen if those cookies would be made http only? They will not be tracked by site analytics snippet? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

As of June 24, 2017, this is changing and ARRAffinity cookies will be set with the HttpOnly flag in the future. https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/12